# my javascript has some mistake in checkbox checking

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in my javascript.
All I want to do is if my user doesnt select any checkbox out given 10 checkboxes then I want to give him an alert else submit the form.
I have written a js code but thats not working even if checkbox is checked. Please point me out my mistake.
Heres my code.

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById('submitbtn').onclick = function() {
                    var count = 0;
                    if(document.getElementById("pid1").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("pid2").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("pid3").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("pid4").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("pid5").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("pid6").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("pid7").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("pid8").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("pid9").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(document.getElementById("pid10").checked == "checked")
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    alert(count);
                    if(count == 0){
                    alert("Please select atleast 1 product");
                    return false;}
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("formreturn").submit();
                        return false;}
                };
    };
```

Comment: `if (document.getElementById("pid8").checked) { ..`

Comment: Could you post your `.html`?

Comment: a checkbox element's .checked property is either true or false, not "checked"

Comment: @ArCiGo My html file doesnt have any problem and checkbox are also right. The same js code has worked for first time but after lil bit changes it didnt work. And it always show count = 0 even if checkboxes are checked.

Comment: @gabereal lemme check.. :)

Comment: For a DOM element, you have to specify `checked="checked"` but in javascript the property `checked` is a Boolean (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement))

Comment: @gabereal you are the absolutely right. Thank u so much :)

Comment: @MukulAgr Check the answers of abhitalks, gabereal and AKX, are the correct way.

Comment: @ArCiGo Yeah I got the answer. Thank u all.. :)

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie: You don't really *have* to specify `checked="checked"`. Its presence is enough. Just `checked`is enough. Anything else is ignored and treated as presence. `checked="notchecked"` will also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer: use checked attribute, it is a boolean, so you don't need to compare it to 'checked'.

Secondly:
rewrite it, so there is less code :)

```
        var count = 0;
        for (var index = 1; index<= 10; index++){
           if(document.getElementById("pid" + index).checked){
                    count++;
           }
        }
```

Comment: Nitpick: *use checked attribute*: No. We use `checked` property. Attribute doesn't change. Property does.

Answer (score 4):

You should check the `checked` property for truthy/falsy, because the `checked` property is a boolean. Like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("pid8").checked) { ..
```

Even in HTML you don't need to assign the string *"checked"* to the "checked" attribute. Only the presence of this attribute is enough.

You can re-write this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

as this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

In fact you can assign anything to it and it will be ignored and treated as presence.

This will also work:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="DoNotCheck" />
```

---

I see that you are trying to count the number of checked checkboxes. You could do that easily by using a `querySelectorAll`.

***See this Snippet:***

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    var l = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = l;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" /><input type="checkbox" />
<hr />
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Go" />
<p id="result" ></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="some.php" id="myForm" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="some1" value="" id="some1">
    <label for="some1">title of checkbox 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="some2" value="" id="some2">
    <label for="some2">title of checkbox 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="some3" value="" id="some3">
    <label for="some3">title of checkbox 3</label>
</form>


$(function(){

    var form = $("#myForm");

    form.submit(function(e){

       if(form.find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0){

       } else{

       }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `pidX` are `input`s of type `checkbox`, you don't need to compare `.checked` to `"checked"`.

Also, use a loop...

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('submitbtn').onclick = function() {
        var count = 0;
        for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById("pid" + i).checked) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        alert(count);
        if (count == 0) {
            alert("Please select at least 1 product");
            return false;
        }
        document.getElementById("formreturn").submit();
        return false;
    };
};
```